# Why is exporting a query result via SQLite command line shell so slow?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, sqlite, export

To export the result of a query (~45 million records) to a CSV file I used the command line shell:

```
$ sqlite3 db.db3
> .headers on
> .mode csv
> .once result.csv
> select .....
```

This took about 9 hours to run. I then used Python:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db3')
df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

This took about 20 minutes. I understand why Python might be a little bit faster but did not expect such a huge difference. Why is the SQLite command line shell so slow?

Comment: I have a hunch that the answer might be that the shell tool opens the file and writes for each result of the output, whereas Python writes it in larger batches, but I am interested to hear from someone who knows more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got help with this on the [SQLite forum](https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/3a3d6b54ac).

It seems like much of the running time with the CLI method is serial disk I/O. If we can load the entire query into memory first and then write it, the write time will be comparable.

Here is one example of how to do it:

```
$ sqlite3 db.db3
> attach database ':memory:' as in_memory;
> create table in_memory.large_result as [insert original query here];
> .mode csv
> .headers on
> .once result.csv
> select * from in_memory.large_result;
```